# Dynamically rotate this cube by passing serial data?

Tags: python, scripting

I aim at making an external controller for my blender application. I wish I could rotate dynamically a cube, using post-treated serial data.

This code returns correctly the 2 euler angles computed from serial data sent by an Arduino. The cube won't turn at all.

This is actually my main problem, I will do the cleaning myself in finding why on earth the code won't stop at all, so funny to kill Blender everytime. No talking about these very surprising and funny COM port.

I did probably a great mess in the variables definitions. I do not master nor Class, nor Operator properties. I guess there is something about this.

```py
global arduinoSerialData
global heel
global pitch
global cube

class PrimzahlThread(threading.Thread):

    stop = False

    def __init__(self): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        print("Thread started")

    def run(self):
        while not PrimzahlThread.stop:
                    analoop()
        print("Stopping thread")


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    limits = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)
    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE','ESC'}:
            self.limits = 0
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            action()
            self.limits += 1


        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        thread = PrimzahlThread()
        thread.start()
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(time_step=1/12, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


heel = 0
pitch = 0

def action():
    bpy.context.active_object.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = (heel, pitch, 0)


def analoop():

    arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('COM4',9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialDatax
    arduinoSerialData.setDTR(1)
    print('Access to COM3 granted')

    while True:

        if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
            myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
            time.sleep(1/12)
            #print(myData.decode("utf-8").rstrip()) #Raw data acquisition. Uncomment for use
            myNewData = myData.decode("utf-8").split()
            #print(myNewData)
            x = float(myNewData[0])
            y = float(myNewData[1])
            z = float(myNewData[2])
            heel= math.atan(y/(z+1e-8))*180/3.14*numpy.sign(y)
            pitch = math.asin(-1*x)*180/3.14*numpy.sign(z)
            print("Pitch= {:.0f}".format(pitch)," | Heel = {:.0f}".format(heel))

        else:
            print("No reading...Waiting for available data....")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # Add a cube at the origin.
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```